# Mysql multiple instances can't connect through socket

Tags: mysql, sockets

my.conf

```
[mysqld]

datadir=/var/lib/mysql/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld@1]

socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql1
```

I can connect as `mysql -u root -p` but when I want to connect to second instance like `mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock -u root -p` I have `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I checked for several times that password is correct.

centos 7

Comment: I'd double check because those errors don't lie.

Comment: @tadman I copied string and without --socket it connects, but with it I had access denied :(

Comment: Do you have the same credentials on both instances? If not you'll need to check that you're connecting to the correct one with the correct credentials. It's pretty easy to get this a little confused even with just one instance in play. With two it's twice as complicated.

Comment: @tadman I didn’t create user in second instance, in no instruction mentioned that... And how can I do it? There is no temporary password in log file of second instance. Help me please

Comment: That's a job for `mysqladmin`. Newer versions of MySQL initialize with a random password that's logged wherever your MySQL instance logs, so you may need to find that.

Comment: @tadman I solved it! Thanks a lot! Apparently I copied my log file in some time and lost my temporary password. I created new instance and all solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to set root password with `mysqladmin --socket=path_to_socket -u root -p'temporary password from logs' password new_password`